# How to increase a col by double value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to multiply a col with a double value but getting mismatch error, can somebody please help

GA is double, taking value from a cell which has percentage value by which to increase.

```
With wsData.Range("AC2", wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "AC").End(xlUp))
        wsDest.Range("AL9").Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Copy1").Range("V3").Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value
      End With
    
    For i = LastRow To 9 Step -1
        wdest.Cells(i, "AL") = wdest.Cells(i, "AL") * GA1
    Next
    
    
    End Sub
```

It is giving me a mismatch error

Comment: Is `wdest` different to `wsDest` ?

Comment: Use `IsNumeric` before attempting to multiply the cell value.

Comment: What is `GA1`? Is that variable set anywhere?